# Cannot make HTTP requests after acquiring authorization token

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to access the MSGraph API using the ADAL python package. Here is a code snippet for how I am acquiring the authorization token.

```
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)

#Use this for Client Credentials
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    RESOURCE,
    client_id,
    client_secret
    )
```

I am getting a token back after making this request in this form:

```
{
  "tokenType": "Bearer",
  "_clientId": <clientID>,
  "_authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>",
  "expiresIn": 3599,
  "isMRRT": true,
  "accessToken": <token>,
  "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "expiresOn": "2017-07-13 16:38:11.591687"
}
```

Now, I am using this token in order to make an http request, like so:

```
request_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
h = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['accessToken']}
response = requests.get(url = request_url, headers = h)
```

I'm getting a response back like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f8c634c0-e23a-4f46-8e39-70ed9e35ef68",
      "date": "2017-07-13T19:38:13"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: Why? I have applied the necessary permissions in the Microsoft App Registration portal. I have also managed to get an instance of this request working use the [Microsoft Graph Python connect sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python3-connect-rest-sample), so I know I'm able to access the data. Why can I not get this instance working? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows the access token didn't have enough permission to execute the list users api . You could grant `Read all users' full profiles` (User.Read.All scope) **application permission** for your app :

1. Add `Read all users' full profiles` application permission of microsoft graph in your azure ad application : 
   [image]
2. Grant that application permission by clicking `Grant Permissions` button in above screenshot with admin account of your AAD .
3. Using client credential flow to acquire access token for microsoft graph as your code . After you get the access token , you could decode the token using [online tool](http://jwt.calebb.net/), you should find `User.Read.All` in `roles` claim .
4. Send a list users api with access token .

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hello, thank for your response. I granted permissions and everything in AAD, but now I am getting another weird response. I'm getting a "BadRequest" that says "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request". Do you know why that could be?

Comment: @JohnM.Kovachi , which request throws the error ?You could  use fiddler or IE/Chrome developer tool (network part) to capture the requests .